# How to install American fuzzy lop on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

Using `sudo apt-get install afl` gives

`E: Unable to locate package afl`

on my machine. How can I install American fuzzy lop on Ubuntu?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, it wasn't that hard. I just cloned the source code from a mirror, `make`'d and `make install`'ed:

1. Clone Git repository of `afl`, I use a mirror I found on GitHub:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/mirrorer/afl
   ```
2. Change directory and `make` and `make install`:

   ```
   cd afl
   make && sudo make install
   ```

Of course, there might be some libraries you need to install in order to compile. I did not need to do this.

Comment: Thereafter, use `afl-fuzz` command and viola!

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that on Ubuntu 18 you can just install now, but that version seems to be broken.

```
sudo apt-get install afl
```

After installing and trying to use `afl` it seems that it is broken in Ubuntu 18. So you should still refer to vatsug's answer to install.

Apparently it [will be fixed in Ubuntu 19](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/afl/+bug/1774816).

[Blog post about it being broken](https://www.danielstender.com/blog/afl-ubuntu1804/).

Answer (score 0):

I got an error that said:

```
Package afl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'afl' has no installation candidate
```

On Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa), `sudo apt install afl++` is the right command.